# 1:1 Matching with Uncountable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, real-numbers, infinity

"Consider the two open intervals (0,2) = {x is an element of R such that 0 < x < 2} and {0, infinity)={x is an element of R such that 0 is less than x}, both of which are uncountable sets. Do these two sets have the same cardinality? Explain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the function $\tan\big(\tfrac{\pi}{4}x\big)$ as your bijection between your two intervals.

Comment: How do you know to use this? Thank you for the response!

Comment: You see it in Calculus I. arctan is also a good one to remember!